# toLowerCase does not exist on type. Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, filter, autocomplete, angular-material

I want to create filter for autocomplete material.

My model:

```
 export class Country {
      country_id: number;
      name: string;
       }
```

Call webmethod  ws

```
 this.ws.AllCountry().subscribe(
      countryes => {
        this.countryes = countryes.map((country) => {
          return new Country(country);
        });
      }
    );
```

Create this filter, but does not work:

```
filterStates(val: string) {
    if (val) {
      let filterValue = val.toLowerCase();//toLowerCase does not exist on type Country.
      return this.countryes.filter(name => name.toLowerCase().startsWith(filterValue));
    }
    return this.countryes;
  }
```

Can you suggest me any solution please?

Thank you

Comment: How are you calling `filterStates`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your error is happening on the filter line because you are calling `toLowerCase` on the `Country` object itself.  Try this:

```
filterStates(val: string) {
    if (val) {
      let filterValue = val.toLowerCase();

      // the below line is the change
      return this.countryes.filter(country => country.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(filterValue));
    }
    return this.countryes;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    filterStates(val: string) {
    if (val) {
      let filterValue = val.toLowerCase();//toLowerCase does not exist on type Country.
      return this.countryes.filter(item => item.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(filterValue));
    }
    return this.countryes;
  }
```

You were using country object instead of name property.

Answer (score 1):

In case if you are using jquery in angular 2, use toString function

```
$('#search').val().toString().toLowerCase()
```